# Xamarin Forms buttons got flat inside Grid

Tags: gridview, xamarin.forms, stacklayout

Hi i'm trying to implement a bottom button bar without margins but the behaviour was not the expected.

My buttons got flat while in stackLayout they look good but with the margin.

Also you can see that in the first image the "D" image is cut on the bottom, it seems there is a spacing between the scroll view and the buttons, how can i remove it?

**What I have**

```
var consultorButtons = new Grid()
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Margin = new Thickness(0),
    Padding = new Thickness(0),
    RowSpacing = 0,
    ColumnSpacing = 0,

};

consultorButtons.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
consultorButtons.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
consultorButtons.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

consultorButtons.Children.Add(
    new Button
    {
        Text = "TELEFONAR",
        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#21c9ae"),
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Margin = new Thickness(0),
        FontSize = 14
    }, 0, 0);

consultorButtons.Children.Add(
    new Button
    {
        Text = "EMAIL",
        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#272f57"),
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        TextColor = Color.White,
        Margin = new Thickness(0),
        FontSize = 14
    }, 1, 0);
```

**Grid**

[image: Grid]

**StackLayout**

[image: Stack]

Comment: Have you tried by giving "Auto" row height instead of 1 star?

Comment: Oh found it `consultorButtons.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });`

Comment: It works ty build your answer so i can mark it correct

Comment: You can see that the buttons have a slight top margin on the first image can you add how can i remove it?

Comment: can you please add some background color to differentiate extra margin on top, I'm not able to find in current image.

Comment: just realised it is not a grid margin. It is the spacing between the scrollView and the grid. Any ideas on how to remove it?

Comment: In which control, you have placed this two controls? If its in StackLayout then place Spacing="0" in that, If not thenI need to see code for better understanding.

Comment: great the `Spacing=0` worked you may want to add it to your answer

Comment: can you please make new question or edit existing one, after that only I will make it as an answer as it should be reflecting to your question

Comment: @MShah i've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change row height to Auto like this to solve your issue:

```
consultorButtons.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
```

To remove extra space between scroll View and buttons write `Spacing="0"` in the `<StackLayout>`, inside which you have placed this two controls.

Hope this may solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are not reserving enough space for your Grid. That's why the buttons shrink.

Try to add a specific height to the main grid, since your Child Buttons  have the option FillAndExpand.

```
var consultorButtons = new Grid()
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Margin = new Thickness(0),
    Padding = new Thickness(0),
    HeightRequest=70, // Have your height request here
    RowSpacing = 0,
    ColumnSpacing = 0,

};
```

You can also set the `RowDefinition` to `Auto`, however, for performance reasons, is not very good, since you are increasing the layout cicle calculations.

Comment: HeightRequest wont behave differently in multiple resolutions?

Comment: It will adjust to the different resolutions.

Comment: buttons get too big on IOS. i'll stick with the first solution.